# Making Emacs and Cask work on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, emacs

I am arriving now to the Emacs world coming from Vim. I have been slowly trying to create a starters .emacs.d and started to meddle today with Cask. 
I had no problems setting up Cask in Debian, but I just can't seem to do it on Mac OSX.

I installed Emacs using homebrew:

```
brew install emacs --HEAD --use-git-head --cocoa --with-gnutls --with-rsvg --with-imagemagick
```

When I tried to set up Cask following the instructions on the [readthedocs page](http://cask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) with no success. I tried both homebrew, git clone and curl methods and the outcome is always the same. Whenever I enter $ cask

I get this

```
Importing package-keyring.gpg...
Importing package-keyring.gpg...done
Failed to download ‘melpa’ archive.
Package refresh done
Failed to download ‘gnu’ archive.
Setting ‘package-selected-packages’ temporarily since "emacs -q" would overwrite customizations
Setting ‘package-selected-packages’ temporarily since "emacs -q" would overwrite customizations
Package ‘s-’ is unavailable
```

This is driving me specially nuts because, as I said above, it took me 2 min to set it up on Debian.

Thanks

PS: Similar problem can be found on [this page](https://travis-ci.org/coldnew/coldnew-spacemacs)

Answer (score 1):

A regression was introduced in the Emacs's `master` branch in `package.el`. The problem was fixed in the release branch for Emacs 25, but the fix hasn't been merged in `master` yet. I expect this will happen soon.

Comment: Ok thank you. I will either wait or maybe go with some other version.

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail on what the problem was? I'm seeing this on Travis, and I'm not sure what's causing it. Thanks!